# Nginx Not Loading All Images Properly: Upstream Response Buffer?

Tags: nginx

I have a Wordpress site running Apache/Reverse Nginx. After adding a subdomain my nginx continues to pull images from the IP rather than the domain, how can I specify it to pull images from a domain?

My issue is that not all images are loaded and some appear missing even if they exist. In my logs all I could find was "upstream response is buffered", however after increasing my buffers the problem persists.

What can be causing such an issue? It clearly shows a 404 - this started happening after I added a subdomain account and had to change DocumentRoot in Apache.

Any ideas?

Update: The error seems to appear more frequently when hitting REFRESH (CTRL + R)

```
proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
proxy_buffering on;
#proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60m;
#turn caching on
proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
proxy_send_timeout   300; #600
proxy_read_timeout   600; #600
proxy_buffer_size    256k;  ####64k
proxy_buffers     100 256k;##16 32k
proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k; #64
proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;#64k
#larger
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; ####2048m
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_hide_header  Vary;
proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding '';
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
proxy_ignore_headers  "Set-Cookie";
```

Comment: I added this now: proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60m;
proxy_cache_valid 400 1m;
Maybe that works

Comment: "my nginx continues to pull images from the IP rather than the domain" what does this even mean?